# regex match regardless of spacing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace an old function call with an updated function.

I'm looking for something like this:

`$myvar         = myclass::getmyvar();`

However the tabs / spacing can vary wildly due to code formatting. How can I match for any number of tabs or spaces between the `$myvar` and the `= myclass::getmyvar();`?

I've tried variations of something like this:

`$myvar[* \t]=[* ]myclass::getmyvar();`

without success.

I'd like to pass it to a statement like the following:

```
grep -rl '$myvar[* \t]=[* ]myclass::getmyvar();' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/$myvar[* \t]=[* ]myclass::myvar();/$myvar = mynewclass::myvar();/g'
```

Is that the proper syntax, or should I be using egrep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem lies with the location of your `*` and not escaping `$`, `(` and `)`. This will yield better results.

```
\$myvar[ \t]*=[ ]*myclass::getmyvar\(\);
```

In addition, you can update it to match any whitespace using `\s` instead of character classes.

```
\$myvar\s*=\s*myclass::getmyvar\(\);
```

Comment: thanks! this does indeed work. However, when I pass the argument to sed, the string is not being replaced. Is there a different syntax in sed? Please see my amended question.

Comment: `sed` and `grep` use [GNU BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#bre) syntax by default, which means you should **not** escape the parentheses.  `()` matches the literal character sequence `()`, while `\(\)` captures an empty string.  Alternatively, you can force them to use the [ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere) syntax by using `sed -r` and `grep -e` or `egrep`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `\s*`, meaning `0 or more whitespace characters`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `*` outside of the character class, so to match any number of spaces or tabs you can use the following in your regex:

```
[ \t]*
```

You could use `\s*` as well, but note that this will also match line break characters, and it sounds like you are only interested in tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this.  You shouldn't include the * in the [] braces, and escape the $ and () braces:

```
\$myvar[\s\t]*?=[\t\s]*?myclass::getmyvar\(\);
```

Include *? to make the regex ungreedy.